# How would the chart around a point vary be different to the tangent space at the same point?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

If I'm not mistaken, the tangent space and the space that a chart maps to are both Euclidean. So if I take some points from a neighbourhood around a point on the manifold, and map them to Eulclidean space with a chart; how might they be different to the collection of tangent vectors I would get were I to use the exponential map to map them to the points tangent space?

Comment: Technically, given a point $p$ on the manifold, you can say that there is some correspondence between the points close to $p$ and small tangent vectors at $p$. But the actual correspondence you get is completely chart dependent (which is not a good thing), and for points far away, or for large tangent vectors, that correspondence falls apart completely.

Comment: But if I measure the distances between my points in either of these spaces, won't they both become less accurate the further I stray from p?